# How can I write simple custom Android Handler class?

Tags: java, android

It's interesting for me how it's possible to write simple Android Handler class using only pure java to send signals from one thread to another?

I saw the source code:
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/os/Handler.java

But how for example to write class (Handler class) that can send for example int value from one thread to another(not using share data(like in Android Handler?))?

Comment: No one tried to do it or maybe question is dummy?

Answer (score 6):

If you have the thread in the same method as the handler receiving the message you can do like this:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
             // do something
    }
}

final Thread th = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
            // do something than send an integer - x in our case
            int x = 0;         
            final Message msg = Message.obtain(handler, x, null);
            handler.dispatchMessage(msg);
        }
    };
th.start();
```

If your handler can't be accessed directly from the thread than create a class extending Thread and pass the handler to the class's constructor.

Comment: I know what Android Handler is and what it's purposes.I want to know how to write simple custom Handler with very basic functions to understand hot it work

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the question right the first time. Without using something OS specific I do not think it's possible. If someone managed to do this I would also be curious how.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can create your own CustomHandler like android handler by using only Java Api's .

```
private class CustomHandler {

private final Runnable POISON = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {}
};

private final BlockingQueue<Runnable> mQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

public CustomHandler() {
    initWorkerThread();
}

private void initWorkerThread() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d("CustomHandler", "worker (looper) thread initialized");
            while (true) {
                Runnable runnable;
                try {
                    runnable = mQueue.take();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    return;
                }
                if (runnable == POISON) {
                    Log.d("CustomHandler", "poison data detected; stopping working thread");
                    return;
                }
                runnable.run();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

public void stop() {
    Log.d("CustomHandler", "injecting poison data into the queue");
    mQueue.clear();
    mQueue.add(POISON);
}

public void post(Runnable job) {
    mQueue.add(job);
}
}
```

And I would like to point at the question itself that you donot use handler to pass int values from one thread to another. Handlers are use to run tasks in another thread. If you want to share a variable between two threads, consider using volatile keyword and atomic variables.